# Do we know what Avodah means?

Tags: words, tanach

Parallel to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66720/how-do-we-know-when-the-word-%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2-means-intercourse-or-just-brain-knowledge).

The root ayin-vet-dalet seems to have three separate uses according to the Even Shoshan:

as a noun, eved means A) a person who is owned by another or who is forced to work for another, B) a nickname for someone trusted by and loyal to Hashem C) a way a person refers to himself when speaking to someone greater than he

as a verb, avad refers to (depending on conjugation) A) did work B) worked for another person B') placed work on another C) fulfilled the commandments of a deity

as a noun Avodah refers to A) physical work B) task C) religious performance

Other than by interpretation (using context or tradition) is there any way to see the specific meaning (grammar, punctuation, trope, speaker etc)?

For example, Hashem (Shemot 4 and forward) tells Moshe to have Par'oh release the people (slaves) so that the people can "Serve" Hashem, but the roots are the same. One could reread the lines to mean that the people worship Par'oh and have to be enslaved to Hashem. In Yeshayahu 28:21 Hashem performs "tasks that are astounding" (נָכְרִיָּ֖ה [עֲבֹדָתֽוֹ](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.28.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) but someone could misread it to think that the tasks are physical actions done by a physical being and not tasks/functions (though, yes, the lines are much blurrier here)

Do we know, external to post facto interpretation, what the text meant in each case of the use of the root and its forms?

Comment: How is this different from any other word with multiple meanings that must be decided by context.